# Implement interface where variable is also a method

Tags: javascript, typescript, hapi.js

How would one go about instantiating an interface (`d.ts`) of this sort?

```
export interface IReply {
    <T>(err: Error, result?: string | number | boolean | Buffer | stream.Stream | IPromise<T> | T, credentialData?: any): IBoom;
    <T>(result: string | number | boolean | Buffer | stream.Stream | IPromise<T> | T): Response;
    continue(credentialData?: any): void;
    //...
}
```

With the goal being to call this function (`hapi` handler function) :

```
static healthcheck: ISessionHandler = (request: Request, reply: IReply): void => {

    reply({healthy: true});
};
```

In a manner such as this one:

```
HealthcheckController.healthcheck(request, (reply) => {

    console.log('reply : ' + reply);
});
```

If I remove the typing requirements, this all works -> valid JavaScript. But can't seem to get it to work in TypeScript. It's failing on tsc.

I cannot seem to instantiate a `reply` variable that allows me to successfully call my `healthcheck` function using TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like in (a bit simplified) sample below:

```
export interface IReply 
{
    (result: any): string;
    continue(credentialData?: any): void;
}

let healthCheck = (reply: IReply): void => 
{
    reply({healthy: true});
};

var f = <IReply>((reply: any) => { console.log("reply: ",  reply); return reply; });
f.continue = (credentialData?: any) => { console.log("continue: ", credentialData)};

healthCheck(f);
```

Comment: So if I understand properly, you can't really use it as a callback?  Even though the concept works in pure javascript, TypeScript doesn't quite let it happen.

Comment: I have made a minor edit to be a bit closer to your original example. Isn't it doing exactly what have you asked for?